# Redefining variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have code which replaces `document.write`, makes a buffer and than pushes buffer into the document:

```
var lazyLoad = (function () {

    var CONFIG = {
        block: '',
        url: ''
    };

    function work(){
        buffer = ''
        d.write = d.writeln = function(s){ 
                                    buffer += s
                                }
        d.open = d.close = function(){}
        s = d.createElement('script');       
        s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        s.setAttribute('src',CONFIG.url);
        d.getElementById(CONFIG.block).appendChild(s)
        s.onload = function () {
            window.setTimeout(function() {

                console.warn(CONFIG.block + ' ' + buffer)
                d.getElementById(CONFIG.block).innerHTML += buffer;
                buffer = '';
            }, 0);
       }
    }

    return {
            init: function (options) {
                $.extend(CONFIG, options);

                window.d = document
                window.onload = function(){
                    work()
                }
            }

    }

})();
```

If I init it once:

```
lazyLoad.init({
            url: 'http://test1.com/test1.js',
            block: DIVID1
        })
```

But if I call it again with other parameters:

```
lazyLoad.init({
                url: 'http://test2.com/test2.js',
                block: DIVID2
            })
```

First init wont work. `buffer` will be empty. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

By calling `$.extend(CONFIG, options)`, you're replacing the previous config with the new one.

Instead, you should create an array and append each `options` to it.

Comment: I have problems with `buffer`. After first init it is empty, but after second it has some code. I think `$.extend` doesn't replace my buffer.